# compilation on Blue Gene Q - ELF header

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-errors, cross-compiling, hpc

I compiled patched software on BGQ with gcc compilers - for reasons which I do not understand I have huge problems with compiling this with the standard IBM XL compilers...

Software compiled and it runs on access node ok but when I am trying to run job in queue I got this error:

```
Load failed on R00-IC-J01: Application executable ELF header contains invalid value, errno 8 Exec format error
```

Any ideas? Does it mean that I should compile this with XL?
Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest tagging this "cross-compile" and "hpc" to get the relevant audience.  I'm surprised there's no "Blue Gene" tag on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

You say "software compiled and it runs on access node ok", but that's not how blue gene works.  One has to cross compile for the compute nodes: executable that work on the login node will not work on the compute nodes.

OK, that's not 100% true: if your application avoids back-end specific things (no QPX instructions, no CNK-specific features) it's possible a simple compute node program might work on the access node.

You need to compile your program with the blue gene tool chain.  On Argonne's BGQ (Mira, Cetus, Vesta), the GCC cross compilers are in `/bgsys/drivers/ppcfloor/gnu-linux/bin` and the IBM cross compilers are in `/soft/compilers/ibmcmp-may2013/vac/bg/12.1/bin/bgxlc_r` .  If you're not at Argonne, ask your support staff.

Comment: A Blue Gene compute program can run on the login or I/O nodes, but usually does not.  Its not related to standard Linux syscalls though, those are compatible.  

If the program 1) uses QPX, it will be limited to the compute node only as QPX instructions are illegal on other POWER hardware.  2) uses Blue Gene/Q devices or CNK-specific features, it will fail.  So MPI-using programs will (always?) fail.  But basic do some file I/O, calculate, printf codes should be fine.